# Loop to Create and save dataframes into list

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I have example code and data below.  What I'm trying to figure out is how write a loop that would create say x (in this example x=3) dataframes from a dataframe (in this example datadf) and save those dataframes in a list.  The main part I'm stuck on is how to save each dataframe into a list.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

The updated code below seems to just about work, except the beginning index on the dataframes always stays at 1, instead of stepping 10 ahead each time.  Anybody know what the issue is?

Update:

```
N<-3
x<-vector("list",N)
for (i in 1:N)
{
  a<-(1:100)*rnorm(1,0.5)
  b<-(1:100)*rnorm(1,2)

  datadf<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

  n<-10
  t<-50


  datadfn<-datadf[((i-1)*n+1):(t+2*(i-1)*n),]


  x[[i]]<-datadfn

}    
Example Code:

n<-10
t<-50

datadf1<-datadf[1:t,]
datadf2<-datadf[(n+1):(t+n),]
datadf3<-datadf[(2*n+1):(t+2*n),]

dfList<-list(datadf1, datadf2, datadf3)


Data:

dput(datadf)
structure(list(a = c(2.00134717160119, 4.00269434320238, 6.00404151480358, 
8.00538868640477, 10.006735858006, 12.0080830296072, 14.0094302012083, 
16.0107773728095, 18.0121245444107, 20.0134717160119, 22.0148188876131, 
24.0161660592143, 26.0175132308155, 28.0188604024167, 30.0202075740179, 
32.0215547456191, 34.0229019172203, 36.0242490888215, 38.0255962604226, 
40.0269434320238, 42.028290603625, 44.0296377752262, 46.0309849468274, 
48.0323321184286, 50.0336792900298, 52.035026461631, 54.0363736332322, 
56.0377208048334, 58.0390679764346, 60.0404151480358, 62.041762319637, 
64.0431094912381, 66.0444566628393, 68.0458038344405, 70.0471510060417, 
72.0484981776429, 74.0498453492441, 76.0511925208453, 78.0525396924465, 
80.0538868640477, 82.0552340356489, 84.0565812072501, 86.0579283788513, 
88.0592755504524, 90.0606227220536, 92.0619698936548, 94.063317065256, 
96.0646642368572, 98.0660114084584, 100.06735858006, 102.068705751661, 
104.070052923262, 106.071400094863, 108.072747266464, 110.074094438066, 
112.075441609667, 114.076788781268, 116.078135952869, 118.07948312447, 
120.080830296072, 122.082177467673, 124.083524639274, 126.084871810875, 
128.086218982476, 130.087566154077, 132.088913325679, 134.09026049728, 
136.091607668881, 138.092954840482, 140.094302012083, 142.095649183685, 
144.096996355286, 146.098343526887, 148.099690698488, 150.101037870089, 
152.102385041691, 154.103732213292, 156.105079384893, 158.106426556494, 
160.107773728095, 162.109120899697, 164.110468071298, 166.111815242899, 
168.1131624145, 170.114509586101, 172.115856757703, 174.117203929304, 
176.118551100905, 178.119898272506, 180.121245444107, 182.122592615708, 
184.12393978731, 186.125286958911, 188.126634130512, 190.127981302113, 
192.129328473714, 194.130675645316, 196.132022816917, 198.133369988518, 
200.134717160119), b = c(2.05061146723527, 4.10122293447054, 
6.15183440170581, 8.20244586894108, 10.2530573361764, 12.3036688034116, 
14.3542802706469, 16.4048917378822, 18.4555032051174, 20.5061146723527, 
22.556726139588, 24.6073376068232, 26.6579490740585, 28.7085605412938, 
30.7591720085291, 32.8097834757643, 34.8603949429996, 36.9110064102349, 
38.9616178774701, 41.0122293447054, 43.0628408119407, 45.113452279176, 
47.1640637464112, 49.2146752136465, 51.2652866808818, 53.315898148117, 
55.3665096153523, 57.4171210825876, 59.4677325498228, 61.5183440170581, 
63.5689554842934, 65.6195669515287, 67.6701784187639, 69.7207898859992, 
71.7714013532345, 73.8220128204697, 75.872624287705, 77.9232357549403, 
79.9738472221756, 82.0244586894108, 84.0750701566461, 86.1256816238814, 
88.1762930911166, 90.2269045583519, 92.2775160255872, 94.3281274928224, 
96.3787389600577, 98.429350427293, 100.479961894528, 102.530573361764, 
104.581184828999, 106.631796296234, 108.682407763469, 110.733019230705, 
112.78363069794, 114.834242165175, 116.88485363241, 118.935465099646, 
120.986076566881, 123.036688034116, 125.087299501351, 127.137910968587, 
129.188522435822, 131.239133903057, 133.289745370293, 135.340356837528, 
137.390968304763, 139.441579771998, 141.492191239234, 143.542802706469, 
145.593414173704, 147.644025640939, 149.694637108175, 151.74524857541, 
153.795860042645, 155.846471509881, 157.897082977116, 159.947694444351, 
161.998305911586, 164.048917378822, 166.099528846057, 168.150140313292, 
170.200751780527, 172.251363247763, 174.301974714998, 176.352586182233, 
178.403197649469, 180.453809116704, 182.504420583939, 184.555032051174, 
186.60564351841, 188.656254985645, 190.70686645288, 192.757477920115, 
194.808089387351, 196.858700854586, 198.909312321821, 200.959923789056, 
203.010535256292, 205.061146723527)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please explain: *except the beginning index on the dataframe always stays at 1*

Comment: when `i=1`, `datadfn <- datadf[0:50,]`.

Comment: @Parfait Sorry I wasn't more clear.  If I run the updated code I get 3 dataframes.  The first has 50 rows, the second has 60, and the third has 70.  I intended for all 3 dataframes to have 50 rows but the beginning index doesn't seem to be iterating forward correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your second expression `(t+2*(i-1)*n)` to `(t+(i-1)*n)` or to align with first expression `((i-1)*n+t)`. Also, consider `lapply` over the `for` loop as its return is a list equal to input `seq(N)` or `[1] 1 2 3`:

```
N <- 3
n<-10
t<-50

dfList <- lapply(seq(N), function(i) {      
  a <- (1:100)*rnorm(1,0.5)
  b <- (1:100)*rnorm(1,2)

  datadf <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
  datadf[((i-1)*n+1):((i-1)*n+t),]
})
```

Or an easier read:

```
dfList <- lapply(seq(N), function(i) {      
  a <- (1:100)*rnorm(1,0.5)
  b <- (1:100)*rnorm(1,2)
  s <- (i-1)*n

  datadf <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
  datadf[(s+1):(s+t),]
})
```